# How do I derive a formula for this ∏ notation?

Tags: induction

> For $n\in\Bbb N$ and $n\ge 2$, find and prove a formula for $\prod_{i=2}^n\left(1-\frac1{i^2}\right)$.

I can easily prove the formula using induction once I have the equivalent result but I'm having a bit of trouble actually finding said formula. I know I can separate the $1 - 1/i^2$ into two different large product notations but after that I've hit a wall. How do I proceed?

Comment: You should use formatting and post the formula here

Comment: Brian M Scott just did that for me. Thank you Brian!

Comment: Shailesh’s comment is a bit harsh, considering that you’re a new user, but if you’re going to be around much, it would be a good idea to learn how to use MathJax to write mathematical expressions; there’s a tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I removed the [tag:pi] tag: it’s specifically for results about $\pi$, not the product operator. (You’re welcome!)

Comment: That's good , but please take the time to learn . I do not mean to be harsh , apologies if it has come out that way

Comment: It didn't come off that way at all. I'm glad to be a new part of this community and I'll make sure to correctly format next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT: Note that

$$1-\frac1{i^2}=\frac{i^2-1}{i^2}=\frac{(i-1)(i+1)}{i^2}=\frac{i-1}i\cdot\frac{i+1}i\;.$$

Now write out the products for a few small values of $n$. For instance, for $n=4$ we get

$$\left(\frac12\cdot\frac32\right)\cdot\left(\frac23\cdot\frac43\right)\cdot\left(\frac34\cdot\frac54\right)=\frac12\cdot\left(\frac32\cdot\frac23\right)\cdot\left(\frac43\cdot\frac34\right)\cdot\frac54\;.$$

If you do this for $n=2,3,4,5$, and maybe $6$, I think that you’ll be able to spot the result.

Comment: I didn't realize that I just needed to figure out a pattern by inputting the numbers. I got the result n+1/2n Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @JollyGoodSir: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 5):

We can write the product as

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{i=2}^n\left(1-\frac1{i^2}\right)&=\frac{\prod_{i=2}^n(i^2-1)}{\prod_{i=2}^ni^2}\\\\
&=\frac{\prod_{i=2}^n(i+1)\prod_{i=2}^n(i-1)}{\prod_{i=2}^ni^2}\\\\
&=\frac{\frac12(n+1)!\,(n-1)!}{(n!)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{n+1}{2n}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, factorising is the way to go, but just two factors is not sufficient. 
$$\prod_{i=2}^n\Big(1-\frac 1{i^2}\Big) = \prod_{i=2}^n\dfrac{(i-1)\cdot(i+1)}{i\cdot i}$$

Can you finish from here?